# can the swap be used to clear std::set as vector ?

Tags: c++

can swap function be used to free memory as in case of vectors as mentioned below?

```
     std::vector<int> v1;

     // somehow increase capacity

    std::vector<int>().swap(v1);
```

Comment: Where does the std::set come in?

Comment: I'm confused: what `std::set` are you talking about, and why not `std::set<int> myset; myset.clear();` ?

Comment: @Nobody I think he's wondering if the same thing can be done with `set`

Comment: @Nobody my question is can the same be done in case of set which i have posted here in case of vectors as in vectors this can be done . Because set are implemented by red black tree concept, While vectors are not

Comment: You should have written this in the question so there would have been no confusion about it :) About your question: Why don't you free the memory via clear()?

Comment: @Nobody I saw somewhere that clear will not free the memory associated . So had the doubt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but are you asking if it is possible to empty a set in the same way?

If so, then yes. :)

Comment: exactly my uestion was same as you interpreted jalf .. Thanks a lot

Comment: i hope using swap with set will free all the memory allocated to that set ? Am i right?

Comment: @Ritesh Yes, but calling `clear()` would also do this. There's no reason to do the swap. I think you might be confusing calling `vector<int>::clear()` with calling `vector<int*>::clear()`.

Comment: @Sancho then how can we clear the memory ? As i mentioned by using swap can we do that ?

Comment: I think you're correct. It was a bit ambiguous what memory you were referring to. I thought you possibly were talking about vectors of pointers, and their associated memory.

Comment: Yes, doing this will replace your set with an empty one. Your old set gets destroyed, so all its memory gets deallocated.

Answer (score 4):

`swap` for vector is defined to exchange the contents *and capacity* of the two vectors.

`set` doesn't have anything like capacity in its public interface, so it's not defined to swap capacity, just contents. There's no particular reason why a set implementation should over-allocate beyond what it needs. But if it does then there's no standard way to ensure that the "spare" memory is freed, since it's permitted to leave the spare memory where it is on a `swap`.

Comment: my set is globally defined so i just wanted to free its memory as it hold large number of elemnets after my work with it is done . So even if it doesnot have a spare memory , i just wanted to free its memory after the work is done. So i guess swap is the only option i am left with

Comment: @Ritesh: no, swap is completely pointless. It won't have any spare memory. Just call `clear()` on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot , but are you sure clear will free the memory for reuse ?

Comment: I don't know of any implementation of `set` where `clear()` doesn't free all the memory.

Comment: @Ritesh: it's not guaranteed, but as I've said, there's no good reason why `set` should keep memory hanging around, so assume it doesn't. For that matter, there's no guarantee that `set` doesn't allocate a bunch of memory up front even for an empty `set`. It's a quality of implementation issue, so there's nothing portable you can do about it, although `set` is a template so you can check the source. If some implementer decides to waste memory, they can do so. If you're that afraid they might, don't use a global `set` -- you can be pretty sure that once it's destroyed it's not keeping memory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can, this trick allows you to shrink capacity of your vector to zero:

```
std::vector<int> intVec;
intVec.reserve(100);
std::vector<int>().swap(intVec);
```

or

to exact count of elements

```
std::vector<int> intVec;    
intVec.reserve(100);
intVec.push_back(1);
std::cout << intVec.capacity() << std::endl;  // prints 100
std::vector<int>(intVec).swap(intVec);
std::cout << intVec.capacity() << std::endl;  // prints 1
```

for more on that look here:
http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm

Comment: Good info about `vector`, but the question was specifically whether similar tricks apply to `set`.

Answer (score 2):

The rationale of doing it that way with vector is that if you simply use the vector's `clear()` or `resize()` method, it is likely that your size will be logically trimmed to 0 but the allocated memory will remain there for re-use.

If what you want is for it to actually remove the excess memory, then you will swap with the empty vector, which never allocated it in the first place (although it may allocate some).

Doing the same with set may work too if set has allocated some "nodes" and decides to hold on to them for re-use although a set does not have a reserve() function so really it is up to the implementor of STL as to whether to release the memory or hold onto it.

Comment: Thanks anyways i will try to assign the set to new empty set and hope it works in making the preoccupied memory of that set free

Answer (score 1):

The swap trick is probably not very useful with `set` since `set` is not so likely to be keeping excess capacity around.

Also, C++11 adds a `shrink_to_fit()` member to the containers where this is likely to be useful. So just use that, and if it's not available then don't worry about it.